# convert a scraped datetime into time

Tags: python, datetime, web-scraping

I have a time in the following form:

```
"2021-08-11T12:16:04+02:00"
```

which I want to convert into this form:

```
"2021-08-11 14:16:04"
```

I've tried using the `strftime` method but couldn't figure how to convert that `+02:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straight ISO 8601 format.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> x = "2021-08-11T12:16:04+02:00"
>>> datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(x)
datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 11, 12, 16, 4, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tim, but is there a way to determine the ```timedelta```'s seconds automatically from the string, because I'm working with multiple dates and it's possible to find a timezone other than the ```+02:00``` if you know what I mean

Comment: No, I don't know what you mean.  Did you look at my code?  `fromisoformat` has determined the timezone automatically.  I didn't type that.  The last line is the object that `fromisoformat` returned.

Comment: Ohh I understood it now, haha I think I didn't focus pretty much 
Thanks a lot for clarifying.